# How to fix for loops that are not looping or doing anything?

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to make the mailman problem, but the contents of the loops aren't running. I have things that print to say a part is done, (like `System.out.println("start")`) and they all work, but the loops aren't printing what they're supposed to.

```
public class mailmanproblem {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        System.out.println("start");
    
        boolean mailboxes[] = new boolean[100];

        for(int i=0; i>=99; i++) {
            mailboxes[i] = false;
        }
        System.out.println("set all to false");
        //does steps 1-100
        for(int step=1; step>=100; step++) {
            for(int i=step; i>98; i+=step) {
                if(mailboxes[i] = false) mailboxes[i] = true;
                if(mailboxes[i] = true) mailboxes[i] = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("did all steps");
        //checks if true or not and prints
        for(int num=0; num>=99; num++) {
            System.out.println(num+" is "+mailboxes[num]);
        }
        System.out.println("printed results");
    };  
};
```

I don't know what's going on.

I tried to change the `i` variables in each of the loops to see if they were being confused and stuff but the loops still didn't return anything.

Comment: What do you think `i>=99` means in `for(int i=0; i>=99; i++)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your understanding of for loops.
Generally, for most programming languages, for loops are structured like this:

```
for (initialization; boolean; change) {}
```

It runs like this:

1. we start with initialization
2. we check the boolean. It can be a comparison or other statement that returns a boolean result. If it is true, we continue. If it is false, we stop.
3. Perform what's inside the loop
4. Compute the change to anything or your initialized variable
5. Check the boolean again.
6. Continue points 3, 4, and 5 until 5 returns a false boolean. Then, we stop.

Examining your for loops, we can see that your for loops don't even loop because your conditional boolean is false from the start. You make `i = 0`, then you check if `i>98` or `i>=99`, etc. Since 0 is clearly not greater than 98 or 99, your loop immediately terminates.

To fix this, flip your `>` signs to `<` signs. Then this process will happen:

1. i = 0
2. i < 99, since 0 < 99, pass
3. execute code inside the loop
4. add 1 to i or variable value to i
   Your loop will continue executing until you add into i makes i greater than whatever number you put.

At the end of the day, just change the following statements, and you'll be okay.

Place 1: Before:

```
for(int i=0; i>=99; i++) // Before
```

After:

```
for(int i=0; i<=99; i++) // After
```

Place 2: Before:

```
for(int step=1; step>=100; step++) // Before
```

After:

```
for(int step=1; step<=100; step++) // After
```

Place 3: Before:

```
for(int i=step; i>98; i+=step) // Before
```

After:

```
for(int i=step; i<98; i+=step) // After
```

Place 4: Before:

```
for(int num=0; num>=99; num++) // Before
```

After:

```
for(int num=0; num<=99; num++) // After
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually is your loops conditions, all conditions are not right. For example, one of your loops is

```
for(int i=step; i>98; i+=step)
```

You should use <99 instead of >98

```
for (int i = step; i < 99; i += step)
```

Same idea for all the loops like this one:

```
for(int i=0; i>=99; i++)
```

i>=99 should be placed by i<99

Comment: Thank you, I thought the middle inequality was when it terminated.